# INSERT INTO SELECT PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have only just started writing in PHP/MySQl, so you'll understand from the code below, why I'm looking to update it to PDO, there's all kinds on no going on here.

I've been able to perform a basic INSERT using PDO, ie

```
$sql=
"INSERT INTO user_collections
('id','user_id','collection_id')
VALUES('',?,?)";

$insertsql=$db_connect->prepare($sql);
$insertsql->execute(array($newUserID,$collection_id));
```

but I'm stuck on the INSERT INTO... SELECT query below. Bascially, I'm taking information from a form and information from a table and trying to insert into a second table.

```
$sql=
"INSERT INTO table1 (id,user_id,collection_id,sticker_id,status)
SELECT '', '$newUserID' ,'".$_POST['collection_id']."',t2.sticker_number,'N')."'
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.collection_id='".$_POST['collection_id']."'";
$insertsql=mysqli_query($db_connect ,$sql);
```

I know that the above works in it's current state, but obviously not the best design. Can anyone help me to translate it into PDO?

Comment: `('id','user_id','collection_id')` <--- it won't work

Comment: If you return more than 1 row, you cannot do a select where like that, use where in.

Comment: "but I'm stuck on the INSERT INTO... SELECT query below" --- exactly the same actually: replace all variables with placeholders

Comment: @RPM: "If you return more than 1 row, you cannot do a select where like that" --- why do you think so?

Comment: @zerkms, nevermind, I thought he was using a subquery for the where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `user_id`, `collection_id`, `sticker_id`, `status`)
    SELECT '', ?, ?, `t2`.`sticker_number`, 'N'
    FROM `table2` AS `t2`
    WHERE `t2`.`collection_id` = ?
";
```

Now just prepare your query and pass in the `$newUserID`, `$_POST['collection_id']` and `$_POST['collection_id']` as parameters, and you're all done :)